# Is it possible to use LocalStorage in a Chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I made an html page that I was going to make an app for Chrome. When I packaged it and tested it, it didn't work. I saw that the error message said that I couldn't use `localStorage`, but I had to use `chrome.storage` instead. I built the entire thing around localStorage so using `chrome.storage` I would have to rewrite large portions of the code. I would like to know if there is a way that I can use localStorage without giving me an error message. I've already tried using an iframe, but it didn't work. I also want my app to open in its own window. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you creating a chrome app or a chrome extension?

Comment: Why would you write the entire code without even testing it once during development ??

Comment: I have tested it in the browser, but not as an app.

Comment: How are you trying to store your data?  As objects, or strings?  If the former, the error might be because `localStorage` can only store strings.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: I'm storing my data as strings, but the problem is that Chrome apps only allow you to use chrome.storage instead of localStorage, which are used extremely differently. Such as `localStorage.setItem("foo", "bar")` and `localStorage.getItem("foo")`. Chrome storage works like `chrome.storage.sync.set({foo: "bar"}, function(e){})` and `chrome.storage.sync.get("foo", function(e){})`.